# VBA: creating multiple parameters inside with/ end with statement

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013, with-statement

I have code that works with no errors. My question is more out of wanting to learn the syntax of a With/ End With statement that can include multiple parameters. Right now a new ADODB.Command is set and inside a With/ End With the ActiveConnection, the commandType, and the CommandText are included. Then outside the With 5 parameters are created, appended and assigned.

I was wondering if those parameters can also be inside the With/ End With of the ADODB.Command.

Here is my code:

```
Set ADOQD = New ADODB.Command
    With ADOQD
        .ActiveConnection = ADOCon
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "jsp_AddFeedback"
    End With

Set pArrangementID = CreateParameter("@ArrangementID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 15)
ADOQD.Parameters.Append pArrangementID
pArrangementID = Forms("MTDDataCheck").ArrangementID.Value

Set pEditor = ADOQD.CreateParameter("@Editor", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 20)
ADOQD.Parameters.Append pEditor
pEditor = gstrLastEditor

Set pProofer = ADOQD.CreateParameter("@Proofer", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 20)
ADOQD.Parameters.Append pProofer
pProofer = gstrLastProofer

Set pControlName = ADOQD.CreateParameter("@ControlName", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255)
ADOQD.Parameters.Append pControlName
pControlName = lbl.name

Set pComment = ADOQD.CreateParameter("@Comment", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, -1)
ADOQD.Parameters.Append pComment
pComment = reply
```

Here is my attempt:

```
    Set ADOQD = New ADODB.Command
With ADOQD
    .ActiveConnection = ADOCon
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "jsp_DeleteFeedback"
    Set pArrangementID = .CreateParameter("@ArrangementID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 15)
    .Parameters.Append pArrangementID
    pArrangementID = Forms("MTDDataCheck").ArrangementID.Value
    Set pControlName = .CreateParameter("@ControlName", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255)
    .Parameters.Append pControlName
    pControlName = lbl.name
    .Execute
End With
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Any examples are much appreciated.

Thank you.

Code After getting response:

```
Set ADOQD = New ADODB.Command
With ADOQD
    Set .ActiveConnection = ADOCon
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "jsp_AddFeedback"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ArrangementID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 15, Forms("MTDDataCheck").ArrangementID.Value)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Editor", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 20, gstrLastEditor)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Proofer", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 20, gstrLastProofer)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ControlName", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, lbl.name)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Comment", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, -1, reply)
    .Execute
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought

```
ADOQD.Parameters.Append pArrangementID
pArrangementID = Forms("MTDDataCheck").ArrangementID.Value
```

Would actually fail or replace the in-collection parameter with a string ...

Doesn't matter though as you don't need to explicitly create a parameter, supply the value along whith everything else:

```
Set ADOQD = New ADODB.Command
With ADOQD
    SET .ActiveConnection = ADOCon
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "jsp_AddFeedback"

    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ArrangementID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 15, Forms("MTDDataCheck").ArrangementID.Value)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Editor", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 20, gstrLastEditor)
    ...
End With
```

Comment: In your example you are mixing where the values, I think, and that makes it a bit confusing for me to understand. WOuld you at least show me how to properly do one parameter?  In my code there are 3 lines per variable/ parameter. Set = CreateParameter, Append variable, then assign value to variable.

Comment: Typo. The first `.Parameters.Append` creates and appends a param called `@ArrangementID` and gives it a value of whatever `Forms("MTDDataCheck").ArrangementID.Value` is.  It can be done on 1 line without the need for param variables.

Comment: Thank you Alex K. Would you mind checking the latest version of my code: "Code After getting response:" and let me know if it looks correct? Thank you again.

Comment: remove `=` from `= .CreateParameter("@Comment",`